# Error: No files matching the pattern "'./src/views/{tokens,atoms,molecules,organisms}/**/*.scss'" were found

Tags: reactjs, webpack, eslint, stylelint

I am getting error while running **stylelint** command on **windows enviornment**:

**command :**     `"lint-styles": "stylelint ./src/views/{tokens,atoms,molecules,organisms}/**/*.scss --fix",`

**Getting error:**

```
Error: No files matching the pattern "'./src/views/{tokens,atoms,molecules,organisms}/**/*.scss'" were found.
at globby.then (C:\workplace\Ulta\web-common\node_modules\stylelint\lib\standalone.js:212:12)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

**While no error on Mac**. What should I change in it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So issue was with the folder names, I changed `tokens,atoms,molecules,organisms` to `Tokens,Atoms,Molecules,Organisms`.

Because I have folders names starting with **capitals** but in command I was using first letter small. Though it was working on mac as it is.

Answer (score 0):

You need [quotes around your glob](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/usage/cli#usage-examples):

```
"lint-styles": "stylelint \"./src/views/{tokens,atoms,molecules,organisms}/**/*.scss\" --fix"
```